# Random extra space at end of horizontally scrollable table

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm using pygments to display CSS-styled code on a static HTML page, but am running into a weird bug that renders the `<pre>` tag wrongly in Safari. As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fy5okuxf/) when you scroll to the right in the table, the charcoal background (which is set on the `<pre>`) stops before the text stops and the remainder of the text is not very readable.

Some observations:

- This works fine in Chrome
- If I remove the blank line inside the `<pre></pre>` everything works as expected
- Removing the `<span class="s"></span>` works as well
- Adding `overflow: auto` to the `<pre>` gives me 2 scroll bars that scroll independently of each other

I've reduced this problem as much as possible (as seen in the fiddle). The HTML output I can't change, but I can modify the CSS as much as I want, so that's the solution I'm looking for.

I tried this on Safari 9.1 on OS X 10.11.4. Does anyone understand what's going on?

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you share a screen shot its all good from my side

Comment: it looks okay in Firefox / Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following code snippet, see if it helps. Note, I changed your original scrollable content from the entire box to the code area only (excludes line numbers).

It works well on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, tested. It also works fine with larger line numbers.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LsnpLczu/)**

```css
.highlighttable {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.highlighttable .linenos {
  background-color: #C1C2C3;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 1%;
  text-align: right;
}
.highlighttable .code {
  background: #343642;
  position: relative;
}
.highlighttable .highlight {
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.highlighttable .highlight pre {
  color: #C1C2C3;
}
```

```html
<table class="highlighttable">
<tr>
<td class="linenos">
  <div class="linenodiv"><pre>1
2</pre>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="code">
  <div class="highlight"><pre>

let variable = <span class="s">&quot;A very long string goes here and it doesn't span multiple lines but makes the table/div scroll (incorrectly)  instead.&quot;</span></pre>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work as expected on IE 11, will see if I can make a fix for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make this work in the actual project later today. I can live with it not looking great on IE.

Comment: This is almost perfect, the only thing missing here that I can't quite figure out is why the border radius isn't working (in both Chrome and Safari). Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think border radius works well on <table> element, previously you reset it to display:block and it has background color, which makes it to work. But changing it to block will make the <tr>s to be anonymous and probably make things behave differently. Instead of tweaking the <table>, you can apply the radius to the <td>s, see https://jsfiddle.net/6et2d3s2/ it works well.

Comment: This works perfectly, even better that it only scrolls the code part of the table. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

According to the documentation [here](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/) on pygment.org you have some control over the resultant HTML but as you pointed out it is limited.

I have used CSS pseudo and counter-increments for line numbers - being more robust and flexible. Counts are directly linked to each span and ignore anything that should not be a line number (eg comment or text) - as shown in the first example below.

The structure is;

```
<pre>
    var = <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</pre>
```

[image: Result 1]

See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/fy5okuxf/160/).

---

In the following example - the first-child has an inline-block;

[image: Result 2]

See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/fy5okuxf/162/)

---

**Original Answer**

Use the white-space property with nowrap.

```
.highlight pre {
    color: #C1C2C3;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/fy5okuxf/12/)

Below fiddles demo how you can match line-heights for single or multiple lines;

```
.highlight pre {
    color: #C1C2C3;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 2;
}

.highlighttable .linenodiv pre {
    line-height: 2;
    margin:0;
}
```

1. [Multiple Lines](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/fy5okuxf/61/)
2. [Single Line](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/fy5okuxf/62/)

Comment: This seems to only work if I have the number of lines specified in CSS. In reality this could be any number of lines that it should work with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is what I provided based on your structure. Give me an example and I'll make it work.

Comment: In this last fiddle you gave, you use multiple `<pre>`s. I have no control over the HTML as I'm using `pygments` to generate this HTML.

Comment: Your updated answer seems exactly what I want. I'm gonna try this out later today and will report back.

Comment: This appears to work really well, but I've chosen to award the bounty to the other answer because that answer scrolls only in the code part of the table, leaving the line numbers intact. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: No problems, I'm pleased you found the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add `overflow-wrap: break-word` to make it works on safari too. Here you must add it:

```
.highlight pre {
  color: #C1C2C3;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to wrap though, I just want the `<pre>` to extend further so the scrollable area is larger

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the code from `.highlighttable` into the bottom of `.highlight pre`, it works fine in Safari, including the curved borders. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f6qhjrw/)

Comment: Yes, but now I have 2 scroll bars (1 in the table, 1 in the `pre`), which doesn't look good

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow-x: auto;` on the `<pre>` element, so you only get the scrollbar you want (according to your comments to other answers).

```
 .highlight pre {
   color: #C1C2C3;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fy5okuxf/64/

Comment: Getting 2 scroll bars (in the `pre` and the table) with your example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understood your problem but if you apply your background-color to the `highlighttable` class the extra space won't show (even though it will still be there, it's just a fix).

Here is your updated code:

```css
.highlighttable {
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* Just put your grey background here */
  background: #343642;
}

.highlighttable .linenos {
   background-color: #C1C2C3;
   padding: 0 5px;
}

.highlight pre {
  color: #C1C2C3;
}
```

```html
<table class="highlighttable">
<tr>
<td class="linenos">
  <div class="linenodiv"><pre>1
2</pre>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="code">
  <div class="highlight"><pre>

let variable = <span class="s">&quot;A very long string goes here and it doesn't span multiple lines but makes the table/div scroll (incorrectly)  instead.&quot;</span></pre>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution I've found as well. Problem with this is that if you scroll right, then back left and it bounces, the "bouncing" area to the left of the line numbers column has a dark charcoal color as well. Instead I'd want that to be white/transparent.

Comment: Well then I think the last update of @Jabuka answers what you need.